# SinonJS, QUnit and jQuery test run

Tags: javascript, jquery, durandal, qunit, sinon

I have a problem trying to run a test. I want to test a library that makes ajax requests and return a promise for each method (get, post, etc).

On my test I have this:

```
var a = proxy.get("test")
        .done(function () {
            ok(true, "API call - GET - Success");
        })
        .fail(function () {
            ok(false, "API call - GET - Success");
        });

$.when(a).always(function () {
        start();
});
```

The thing is that the test does not run. And the weird thing is that if I remove these lines, it works:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="libs/sinon-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="libs/sinon-qunit-1.0.0.js"></script>
```

The console is not showing any errors, so I don't know what to do. Maybe sinon is doing some strange things with jQuery? Any tips?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. The thing is that I was missing the fakeTimers.

So, is like this:

```
var clock = sinon.useFakeTimers();

var a = proxy.get("test")
    .done(function () {
        ok(true, "API call - GET - Success");
    })
    .fail(function () {
        ok(false, "API call - GET - Success");
    });

clock.tick(50);

$.when(a, b, c, d, e).always(function () {
    start();

    clock.restore();
});
```